# Safari 9 and Bootstrap 4: Row not "floating" under other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a wrapper element with 2 rows inside. They stack properly on all browsers, except Safari 9 and some builds of 10.

```
   <div class="row blog-post">
     <div class="col card blog-post mb-0"></div>
     <!-- WILL NOT STACK UNDER ABOVE DIV ON SAFARI 9 -->
     <div class="row post-meta"></div>
   </div>
```

[Image of Working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXvPa.png)

[Image of Safari 9 Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvfkc.png)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QawxYb)

Live page
http://54.165.158.159/blog/

I have tried a variety of fixes

- row :before :after reset
- explicitly Floating the element

Maybe a flex-box thing?

Thanks for any help.